# Check if all values of a column are equal in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have to get rid of columns that don't add information to my dataset, i.e. columns with the same values in all the entries.

I devised two ways of doing this

1. A way using max and min values:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df.agg(F.min(col)).collect()[0][0] == df.agg(F.max(col)).collect()[0][0]:
        df = df.drop(col)
```

2. Another one, using distinct and count:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df.select(col).distinct().count() == 1:
        df = df.drop(col)
```

Is there a better, faster or more straight forward way to do this?

Comment: You could try using UDF's which should increase performance as opposed to Loops

Comment: @Luke: Could you elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df = df.drop(*(col for col in df.columns if df.select(col).distinct().count() == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the subtract method.

```
df1 = # Sample DataFrame #1
df2 = # Sample DataFrame #2

assert 0 == df1.subtract(df2).count()
assert 0 == df2.subtract(df1).count()
```

Another way is to check the union.

```
assert df1.count() == df1.union(df2).count()
assert df2.count() == df1.union(df2).count()
```